# how can I configure an external server as an EGPU?

Tags: server, nvidia, ssh, cuda

I have a laptop and a desktop with a decent GPU connected via ssh, both running ubuntu 18.04. I would like to send GPU tasks, to the server as an EGPU set up. Both are running cuda, but my laptop runs out of GPU memory, so i would like to send out the GPU intensive tasks. I dont know an efficient way to do that, if anyone knows how to set this up I would surely be interested.  I will be running darknet, and other programs written in C/C++ using openCV

The server GPU from lspci:

```
$lspci
controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] (rev a1)
```

Comment: Your problem is hardware related; not software. Do you have thunderbolt ports on both ends?

Comment: no I dont have thunderbolt, but do I really need that? I just want to send my video stream to the server, have it process the matrix, then send back the processed stream.